# how to check if variable contains a valid ip address

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ip-address, aix

I am writing a shell script program in which I am taking IP address or system name from the user, can anybody tell me how to check if the given IP address or system name is valid. I think ping  will not work, I tried it but I can't come out of it, so is there some other method.

Comment: pls check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575128/shell-script-short-syntax-to-verify-valid-ip

Answer (score 1):

Try this, hope it wi

```
#! /bin/sh

valid_ip()
{
  # Check if IP format is num.num.num.num / num between 0..255
  if [ "$(sipcalc $1 | grep ERR)" != "" ]; then
    echo "incorrect"
    return 1
  fi
  echo "correct"
  return 0
}
```

Comment: +1 Did not know sipcalc existed. But needs additional installation.

Comment: But what if user provides a servername instead of IP. I want to check both

Comment: this check is only for ip, not for the server name.

Comment: Is there any solution to check both

Comment: for server name we need to ping and parse the output. using $(ping -c 2 www.abc.com 2>&1| grep "% packet")

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to use "host"

```
host 192.168.1.dog
Host 192.168.1.dog not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

echo $?
1

host happy
happy.local has address 192.168.1.25

echo $?
0

host 192.168.1.25
25.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer Happy.local.

echo $?
0
```